# Dynamic Object is Causing Selected Index Function to NOT Function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very simple code that doesn't want to work. Basic rundown is that it is 100% functional when I remove the creation of the literal control `(CreateFooter()` method), but completely ignores the `ddnEmail_SelectedIndexChanged1` event when it's there. Here is my code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeDataConnections();    
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CreateFooter();
    }    
}

private void CreateFooter()
{
    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
        lnk.Text = "Home";
        lnk.PostBackUrl = dtURLs.Rows[0]["URLHome"].ToString().Trim();
        pnlNavigation.Controls.Add(lnk);
}

private void InitializeDataConnections()
{
    dbLeadsGeneration = Connect("Leads_Generation");
}


protected void ddnEmail_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response . Write("< script >alert('{0}')< /script >", ddnEmail.SelectedValue.ToString(););
}
```

There is much more code that goes with it, but I have literally commented out EVERYTHING else and traced the root back to this one method. It makes no sense to me. Why would this cause my event to fail?

To be clear, this one change makes the application work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitializeDataConnections();    
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // CreateFooter();
    }    
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Leads Maintenance Manage User.ascx.cs" Inherits="Leads_Maintenance_Manage_User.Leads_Maintenance_Manage_User" %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Report Received</legend>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmail" CssClass="CareersLabel">Email</asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddnEmail" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddnEmail_SelectedIndexChanged1" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
        <legend>Site Navigation</legend>
        <div>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlNavigation"></asp:Panel>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a `ddnEmail` control, which I'm assuming is a DropDownList, and its event doesn't fire when you execute `CreateFooter()`? Can you show us the markup for `ddnEmail` and `pnlNavigation`, please?

Comment: did you see if it hits a breakpoint at page_load event when you have the CreateFooter function ?

Comment: @JWLim Added the markup.

Comment: @Volearix That is so strange. Does the markup you provided reflect the actual version? Is `ddnEmail` inside the Panel? If it's not within the Panel, try setting a breakpoint at the SelectedIndexChanged event to see if it's being called at all.

Comment: @JWLim The code posted up here is literally a copy/paste from my code. It includes EvERYTHING except the namespace declaration. When I inspect the code, everything looks like it should be okay. No clue why this control being created is causing such an issue.

Comment: These are just some shots in the dark, so bear with me. 1. Try setting `EnableViewState="true"` in the Page directive. 2. Make sure no two list items in your DropDownList has the same values. 3. Explicitly set one item as `selected` when populating the DDL. Let me know if any of them work.

Comment: @JWLim Attempted both of these solutions. No luck...

Comment: @JWLim It seems to be linked to the PostBackURL. If I modify it to be an 'OnClick' redirect, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Volearix Hm. Can you post the HTML source generated for the `ddnEmail` control? Include all the options if possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48697/discussion-between-jw-lim-and-volearix)